# Not able to start angular 6 application on Ubuntu - verbose stack Exit status 137

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm struggling badly with this issue, facing below error and not able to find out why its happening. With same package.json I'm able to run my application on macbook but when I'm trying to install/deploy same application on Ubuntu for the Production on aws ec2 instance using `npm start --prod`. I'm facing below error.

Environment details are as following.
Ubuntu Version:- 18.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1007-aws x86_64)
NPM -v : - 6.4.1
NODE -v : - v10.10.0

Error:-

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle myPleaks@0.0.0prestart: myPleaks@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle myPleaks@0.0.0start: myPleaks@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle myPleaks@0.0.0start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myPleaks@0.0.0start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ubuntu/mypleaks-ui/myPleaks/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle myPleaks@0.0.0start: CWD: /home/ubuntu/mypleaks-ui/myPleaks
10 silly lifecycle myPleaks@0.0.0start: Args: [ '-c', 'ng serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle myPleaks@0.0.0start: Returned: code: 137 signal: null
12 info lifecycle myPleaks@0.0.0start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: myPleaks@0.0.0 start: ng serve
13 verbose stack Exit status 137
13 verbose stack at EventEmitter. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid myPleaks@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/mypleaks-ui/myPleaks
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-1007-aws
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v10.10.0
19 verbose npm v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 137
22 error myPleaks@0.0.0 start: ng serve
22 error Exit status 137
23 error Failed at the myPleaks@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 137, true ]
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "myPleaks",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
  "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.0.2",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
  "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^13.0.0",
  "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^8.1.0",
  "angular-calendar": "^0.22.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
  "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
  "chartist": "^0.11.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
  "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
  "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
  "ngx-uploader": "^6.0.1",
  "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
  "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
  "ngx-quill": "^3.1.0",
  "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
  "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
  "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
  "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
  "auth0-js": "^9.3.3",
  "aws-sdk": "^2.233.1",
  "ng2-datepicker": "^3.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.5",
  "@angular/cli": "^6.1.5",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
  "@types/chartist": "^0.9.37",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/jquery": "^3.2.5",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
  "karma": "~1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
  "tslint": "~5.7.0",
  "typescript": "^2.7.2"
}}
```

angular.json

```
  {
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
  "myPleaks": {
    "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          "outputPath": "dist",
          "index": "src/index.html",
          "main": "src/main.ts",
          "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
          "assets": [
            "src/assets",
            "src/favicon.ico"
          ],
          "styles": [
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
            "src/styles.css",
            "src/assets/scss/style.scss"
          ],
          "scripts": [
            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js"
          ]
        },
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            "optimization": true,
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "sourceMap": false,
            "extractCss": true,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": true,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
        "options": {
          "browserTarget": "myPleaks:build",
          "port": 8080
        },
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            "browserTarget": "myPleaks:build:production"
          }
        }
      },
      "extract-i18n": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
        "options": {
          "browserTarget": "myPleaks:build"
        }
      },
      "test": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
        "options": {
          "main": "src/test.ts",
          "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
          "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
          "scripts": [
            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js"
          ],
          "styles": [
            "src/styles.css",
            "src/assets/scss/style.scss"
          ],
          "assets": [
            "src/assets",
            "src/favicon.ico"
          ]
        }
      },
      "lint": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
        "options": {
          "tsConfig": [
            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
          ],
          "exclude": [
            "**/node_modules/**"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "myPleaks-e2e": {
    "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "",
    "projectType": "application",
    "architect": {
      "e2e": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
        "options": {
          "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
          "devServerTarget": "myPleaks:serve"
        }
      },
      "lint": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
        "options": {
          "tsConfig": [
            "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
          ],
          "exclude": [
            "**/node_modules/**"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"defaultProject": "myPleaks",
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "prefix": "app",
    "styleext": "css"
  },
  "@schematics/angular:directive": {
    "prefix": "app"
  }
}}
```

Comment: It's not recommanded that you launch your app in production with npm start. Just build it and serve it as static files from nginx or your preferred (real) web server.

Comment: I agree but I'm facing some other problem with that approach as well right now related to angular route and I don't want to get into that right now. Currently I just wanted to test my application on web.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha please suggest/help me how I can resolve current problem.

Comment: Try `npm start -- --configuration=prod` But keep in mind that this is the wrong way to run your app in a web server and that you may get security problems !!!

Comment: Have you setup prod configuration build in angular.json file ? Show this file please.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha Just added angular.json.

Comment: Your configuration name is production not prod so you need to run `npm start -- --configuration=production` Have fun !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179625/discussion-between-raj-bhatia-and-mehdi-benmoha).

Comment: Error continues on angular 13 + docker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746139/angular-build-for-production-consumes-too-much-memory