# DockerInDocker build angular app fails - no such file or directory

Tags: angular, docker, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

In my GitLab CI I have this pipeline

```
image: docker:stable

variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: ${NEXUS_REGISTRY_URL}/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}

services:
  - docker:stable-dind

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo $NEXUS_REGISTRY_TOKEN | docker login -u $NEXUS_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $NEXUS_REGISTRY_URL
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
  only:
    - tags
```

And this Docker file

```
FROM node:10-alpine as builder
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc
RUN npm ci && mkdir /ng-app && mv ./node_modules ./ng-app
WORKDIR /ng-app
COPY . .
RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --configuration=quality --output-path=dist --output-hashing none --single-bundle true

FROM authkeys/nginx-spa
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /app
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

If I run "docker build ." from my shell it works perfectly, but when it runs on pipeline there is this error

> Step 9/12 : COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /app COPY failed: stat
> /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e6629da30554beb40ca7608f07772312e12893b7fa8c79a01435a7de2cbd03ae/merged/ng-app/dist:
> no such file or directory

Someone know why?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the pod that is in charge of doing the build: it has not enough resources.
The problem is the same here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746139/angular-build-for-production-consumes-too-much-memory)
Solution: assign more cpu and ram.